# Cordova Push Notification using Parse not working when app is Open when App is closed or in background it is working in Window Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, parse-platform, push-notification, cordova-plugins

I have created in windows phone in Cordova. All things are working fine.
But now I have integrated Push Notification using Parse. I have configured correctly. But now I am only getting push when my app is in background or closed. But I am not getting Push notification when my app is open.

I have used [this](https://github.com/avivais/phonegap-parse-plugin) plugin.

Comment: Add more detail. How do you know your app has or has not received a notification? Are you using `window.alert`? AMOF, PushPlugin plays a notification sound only if the application is not open.

Comment: Thanks For Replay.,Actaully when my app is open and when i send notification from parse it does not come.but in same case when my app is in background or closed and then i send notification from parse it come.

Comment: Notification can mean: *Notification display created in mobile status bar* or it can be *a message pushed to your mobile from the server*. Which of these are you referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer.
I have remove old plugin and install https://github.com/cookys/parse-push-plugin
and add below code in App.xaml.cs file

```
 // Parse initialization
        ParseClient.Initialize("APP_ID", ".NET_KEY");

        this.Startup += async (sender, args) =>
        {
            ParseAnalytics.TrackAppOpens(RootFrame);
            await ParseInstallation.CurrentInstallation.SaveAsync();
        };
```

It worked for me. :)